# Permission issues with githook

Tags: git, github

I am new to the world of git and git hook. I don't want to use sftp to upload the files to my server. I want to do it using githooks. So I created a file folder 
`/var/site_files/site.git`
and ran `git init --bare` command. Then, I created the following file. 
`var/site_files/site.git/hooks/post-receive` and added the following lines into it
`#!/bin/bash
git --work-tree=/var/www/my_site.com --git-dir=/var/site_files/site.git checkout -f`

I also added a remote (named production) on my local machine.
When I use `git push production master`, I get the following error for all the files:

`remote: error: unable to unlink old '.env.example' (Permission denied)
remote: error: unable to unlink old '.gitattributes' (Permission denied)`

what permissions do I need to set for my `/var/site_files/` folder?
My current permissions are as follows:
`drwxrwxr-x  3 myname myname 4096 Apr 19 15:05 site_files`

Do I need to change the permissions for `/var/www/my_site.com` folder?

Comment: Git hooks run as the user who receives the incoming data. That depends on which Git protocol you use: e.g., `git push ssh://user@host.dom.ain/...` logs in as `user`, while `git push https://...` does whatever the HTTPS server does, which depends on your server. The remaining details are quite OS-dependent, and may go deeper than that as well (e.g., SELinux basically means no one is allowed to touch anything ever :-) ).

Comment: I got my answer. I had to change the permission for my document root folder. Document root was created by the root whereas with git hook I was trying to push changes as another user.
Just had to run sudo chown -R `whoami`:`id -gn` /var/www/my_site.com

Comment: @PritamBohra you should post that as an answer, not as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I got my answer. I had to change the permission for my document root folder. Document root was created by the root whereas with git hook I was trying to push changes as another user. Just had to run 
`sudo chown -R whoami:id -gn /var/www/my_site.com`